# How to use Azure pipelines for private pods?

Tags: cocoapods, azure-pipelines, serviceconnection

I have a collection of private Cocoapods libraries hosted on Github (private repositories), managed by an Azure Devops platform.

I have one AD project for each pod.

The point is, when I try to execute `pod repo add` or `pod install` (I perform this on bash scripts), I need to get an access to my private spec and pods repositories.

I have the option to use a Private Access Token as a secret variable, or an SSH key as a secure file, but then I need to deploy it on each of my projects.

`git config --global url."https://$(username):$(token)@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com"`

Since it can be shared accross projects within the same organisation, I was wondering if there was a way to use the service connection to do that? Is there a way to get it in the script? Do I absolutely need to create my own AD extension for it?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a way to use the service connection to do that? Is there a way to get it in the script?

I am afraid that the service connection couldn't be used in your bash script. In azure devops, the service connection needs to be used in a specific task, and its stored content cannot be read directly by the bash script.

I suggest that you could save your username and token in [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)(`Pipelines -> Library -> Variable Group`).

You could try to use the following PowerShell script to create variable groups for all Organization Projects： API: [Variablegroups - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
[Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json



ForEach( $projectid in $response.value.id )

{

echo $projectid

$url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"

$body = "{       

    `"name`":`"Cocoapodsauth`",
    `"type`":`"Vsts`",
    `"variables`":`
        {`"token`":{`"isSecret`":true,`"value`":`"PAT`"},`"username`":{`"isSecret`":true,`"value`":`"username`"}},
    `"variableGroupProjectReferences`":[
        {
           `"name`":`"Cocoapodsauth`",
            `"projectReference`":
                {
                    `"id`":`"$projectid`"

                    }}]
     



          }"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json

}
```

The above script will traverse all the projects, and then it will create a variable group for each project.

In this case , you could directly use the variable via referring to the Variable Group.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kevin, I missed your answer last week. It will greatly help, thank you! I will try it before accepting the answer, but really thank you for your help

Comment: @CarlSarkis. It's my pleasure to help you. Feel free to let me know if it could meet your requirements